# stop javafx task concurrent

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx, task

I developed a JavaFX application using MVC and DAO patterns. From the user interface the user can press a button to start export from MS Access to SQLite. This may take a long time, so I created a task (in the Controller). The task invokes a method of the Model "exportFromAccessToSQLite". All the logic of the database is in the Model. It all works fine. But I'd like to add a button in the user interface which when pressed stops the current operation. I would like to enter the code in the controller. How can I do?

The code is this:

```
Model objModel = new Model();
Task worker = new Task() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        objModel.exportFromAccessToSQLite(fileAccess, directoryDest);
        updateProgress(1, 1);
        return null;
    }
};
prgEspIndicator.progressProperty().bind(worker.progressProperty());
new Thread(worker).start();
```

Comment: use `worker.cancel() `

Comment: Yes, but I cannot use isCancelled() in the worker. The worker invokes an external method.

Comment: If the external method is not internally programmed to be cancelable or interruptible, then there is not much you can do.  In general, take a close look as the cancellation documentation in the [Task javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) and Brian Goetz's [Interrupting Cancellable Tasks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/).